# Android: display every image from a specific directory

Tags: android

Am am trying to work with this tutorial [here](http://mihaifonoage.blogspot.ie/2009/09/displaying-images-from-sd-card-in.html) which loads every image on the device into a grid view, but im not sure how to modify it to just display images from one particular directory in external storage.

Comment: That's a pretty wide question . you have to put more details on it. What have you tried ,is the directory inside the app or the phone itself?

Comment: Well what happens with this tutorial? It looks like it gets all the images from the external storage and displays them. You should post the code you already have and ask for help on that

Answer (score 0):

Get the folder content with `folder.listFiles()` and create an `Uri` from every entry.

```
String folderName="Photos";
ArrayList<Uri> images = new ArrayList<Uri>();
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
                    + folderName);
File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
        return filename.endsWith(".jpg") || filename.endsWith(".png");
    }
});

for (File file : files) {
    images.add(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
}
```

Then you could use the array list with uris to pass it to the adapter.